# Unknown API Key Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, mern, cloudinary

I am creating a mern stack social media app, in which i am taking photos through multer and storing them in cloudinary, but cloudinary is constantly giving this error:

```
Cloudinary Upload Error: {

message: "Unknown API key '879993354584111',",

name: 'Error',

http_code: 401

}
```

This is my cloudinary configuration:

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary';

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET_KEY,
});

export default cloudinary;
```

This is my createPost function

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { userId, description } = req.body;
        const picturePath = req.file.path;
        console.log("Uploaded File:", req.file);
        console.log("Post request: ", req.body);
        const user = await User.findById(userId);

        if (req.file) {
            // Upload the image to Cloudinary
            try {
                console.log("CLoudinary started...");
                const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(picturePath, {
                    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
                    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET_KEY,
                    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
                });
                console.log("Cloudinary Upload Result:", result);
                const finalPicturePath = result.secure_url;
                console.log("Picture Path:", finalPicturePath);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Cloudinary Upload Error:", error);
            }
        }

        const newPost = new Post({
            userId,
            firstname: user.firstname,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            location: user.location,
            description,
            userPicturePath: user.picturePath,
            picturePath: picturePath,
            likes: {},
            comments: []
        })

        await newPost.save();
        console.log(newPost)

        // const post = await Post.find();

        res.status(201).json({ message: 'Post added successfully' });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me the unknown api key error

I want the image that came through multer to be added to cloudinary, but its giving me this error

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message you receive from Cloudinary, it shows the unknown API key that was sent in your upload request - notice the API Key is within single quotes in the error message. The single quotes should not be part of the value sent in your request. There's also a comma at the end of the string in the `.env` file.

You should be able to resolve it by removing the single quotes from around the values in your `.env` file as well as the trailing comma on each line and retrying the request again.

Comment: Its still giving the same error
Cloudinary Upload Error: {
  message: 'Unknown API key 879993354584111,',
  name: 'Error',
  http_code: 401
}

Comment: @DevBulchandani I see you have a comma at the end of each line as well - you will want to remove that as well before retrying